# What does the vertical plane which passes through the the line of the greatest slope of an inclined plane represent?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, plane-geometry

I encountered a problem while solving a question about friction force regarding static bodies

The Question is as follows,
"A body of weight (W) is placed on a rough plane inclined to the horizontal at an angle whose tangent is 7/24. It is tied to a rope and it is pulled by the rope upwards with a force of magnitude (3/5 W) to make the body about to move upwards the plane. If the rope lies in the vertical plane which passed through the line of the greatest slope and the measure of the angle between the rope and the line of the greatest slope is x where tan(x) = 3/4. Calculate the coefficient of static friction between the body and the plane, also find the measure of the angle of friction".

The Question is straightforward and understandable. However what I want to know is:

What does the statement "lies in the vertical plane which passed through the line of the greatest slope" mean or represent? And how to visualise this system in real life if possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: basically, if you put a ball on top of the plane (slope) and trace its movement downward on this rough plane, you'll get the line of the greatest slope. As for visualizing this, think about pulling a sled uphill using a rope.

Comment: @ViruS [Here is a diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132080/angles-of-lines-in-space-geometry). Slope of $l_2$ is larger than that of $l_3$ and all other lines, passing through weight $W$, in the inclined plane.

Comment: @cosmo5 and Vasya, sorry I didn't elaborate but I understand what line of the greatest slope mean. Basically what I want to know is {(1) what is the vertical plane mentioned in the question? - - - - - (2)How does it pass through the line of the greatest slope? - - - - - (3)How does the rope lie in that vertical plane?} I can't really visualize the system, and visualization is the key to solve the question. Thanks in advance.